# How to extract sent items from Outlook shared mailbox in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to extract emails from a group/shared mailbox in Outlook using the code below in Excel.

`olObjNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)`

Using this I can extract inbox items.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getshareddefaultfolder-method-outlook says "..... olFolderSentMail cannot be specified for this argument."

How do I get 'Sent items' from a shared mailbox?

I tried `olObjNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)` but it retrieves my personal email 'Sent Items'.

Comment: Do you get any errors or exceptions when the `olFolderSentMail` argument is used for the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` function?

Comment: Is adding the mailbox as a delegate store to the current profile an option?

Comment: If fldr(iArr) = "Inbox" Then
            Set olObjFolder = olObjNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)
        ElseIf fldr(iArr) = "Sent Items" Then
            'Set olObjFolder = olObjNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
            Set olObjFolder = olObjNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderSentMail)
        End If
        
        tCnt = olObjFolder.Items.Count ' taking the total count of mailitems in the folder

Comment: There was an error yesterday, but I cannot reproduce it now. The code is shown above. Now it is showing error in the last line....... tCnt = olObjFolder.Items.Count...."Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f): The operation failed."....Also when I checked the variable ?olObjFolder in the immediate window, it shows..."Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f): The attempted operation failed.An object could not be found."

Comment: Has anyone resolved how we can do this without delegating mailbox? Are there other APIs that can do this job?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the shared store, for example by using the following code:

`olObjNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox).Store`

And then use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/store-getdefaultfolder-method-outlook) method of the `Store` class from the Outlook object model. It returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument.

This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Comment: That would only work if the mailbox in question was added to the profile as a delegate store.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the shared mailbox address and given it contains "Sent Items" folder it should do:

```
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner = objNS.CreateRecipient("email@domain.com")
objOwner.Resolve
Set objOutlookFile = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Sent Items")
```

worked well for me ;)